# Python string formatting of multi-level dict

Tags: python, string-formatting

A common technique for rendering values from template strings looks like this:

```
>>> num = 7
>>> template = 'there were {num} dwarves'
>>> print template.format(**locals())
there were 7 dwarves
```

This approach works for any data type that has a `__str__` method, e.g. dicts:

```
>>> data = dict(name='Bob', age=43)
>>> template = 'goofy example 1 {data}'
>>> print template.format(**locals())
goofy example 1 {'age': 43, 'name': 'Bob'}
```

However it doesn't work when a dict item is referenced by key:

```
>>> template = 'goofy example 2 {data["name"]}'
>>> print template.format(**locals())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: '"name"'
```

It's inconvenient, and seems odd, that an identifier that's valid in code outside the format string is invalid when used within the format string.  Am I missing something?  Is there a way to do this?

I'd like to be able to reference an element several layers down in a nested dictionary structure, like `somedict['level1key']['level2key']['level3key']`.  So far my only workable approach has been to copy these values to a scalar variable just for string formatting, which is icky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using `{data[name]}` instead of `{data["name"]}` in the string.

The types of things you can specify in a format string are restricted.  Arbitrary expressions aren't allowed, and keys are interpreted in a simplified way, as described in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> it is not possible to specify arbitrary dictionary keys (e.g., the strings `'10'` or `':-]'`) within a format string.

In this case, you can get your key out because it's a simple alphanumeric string, but, as the docs suggest, you can't always necessarily do it.  If you have weird dict keys, you may have to change them to use them in a format string, or resort to other methods (like concatening string values explicitly with `+`).

Comment: That works, even for a nested dictionary.  A structure like `x = dict(a=dict(b=dict(c=123)))` that could be referenced like `x['a']['b']['c']` in normal code can be referenced like `'{x[a][b][c]}'` in a format string and rendered properly.  Thank you!